# Disable manually tracking dependencies in ApplicationInsights.config

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-application-insights

I want to disable sending of manually tracking dependencies in my project, because they are consuming a lot of resources (data ingested) in my azure.
Also, I want to be able to re-enable for debugging purpose.
The cose used for manually track the dependencies is the following:

```
var ai = new TelemetryClient(TelemetryConfiguration.Active);
ai.TrackDependency(new DependencyTelemetry("User", "CElaboraRichieste", "GetStringXML", "Inizio"));
```

I've successfully removed the automatic dependencies by removing the DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule module in ApplicationInsights.config, but I wasn't able to do the same with manually tracked deps.
Is there a way to accomplish my goal by editing such config and not introducing a new config parameter? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a [TelemetryProcessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#create-a-telemetry-processor) and have it dicard dependency telemetry when not in debug mode (or whatever logic you want to determine whether telemetry should be processed or discarded). For example:

```cs
public class DependencyFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private readonly ITelemetryProcessor _next;

    public DependencyFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        bool isDebugMode = false;
#if DEBUG
        isDebugMode = true;
#endif

        if(item is DependencyTelemetry & !isDebugMode
            return;
        
        _next.Process(item)
    }
}
```

You need to register the processor type in the config file by using the full namespace and type name and assembly:

```xml
<TelemetryProcessors>
  ...
  <Add Type="WebApp.DependencyFilter , WebApp" />
  ...
</TelemetryProcessors>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this is the cleanest and the most appropriate solution.